# Linq select a value based on where condition from other table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have this query:

```
 var result = (from game in db.Games
                    join gameevent in db.Events
                        on game.GameId equals gameevent.GameId into events
                    from _event in events
                    join _targetObjects in db.TargetObjects
                        on _event.TargetObject equals _targetObjects.TargetObjectId into targetss
                    where game.userId == userId
                    select new ProfileViewModel
                    {
                        record = events.Where(s => s.TargetObjectId == _event.TargetObject && _event.EventType == 35).Select(/* Here I want to select a value from targetss, field called TargetName */).ToList()
                    }).First();
```

As you can see, I want to get value based on where clause from other table. Is that possible in the select new part?

I want to get the name of the targetObject based on the targetObjectId which matches the targetObjectId in events table and also the event type should be 35.

Answer (score 1):

If the query starts to become a too complex one then it is worth splitting it into parts.

In my example below I use the extension method syntax of LINQ instead of query keywords just because it is easier for me to use.

```cs
// First we collect the relevant games.
var games =
    db
        .Games
        .Where(game => game.UserId == userId);

// Then we collect the events of the collected games that have the specified event type.
var events = 
    db
        .Events
        .Join(
            games,
            gameEvent => gameEvent.GameId,
            game => game.GameId,
            (gameEvent, game) => gameEvent
        )
        .Where(gameEvent => gameEvent.EventType == 35);

// Then we collect the target objects based on the collected events.
var targetObjects =
    db
        .TargetObjects
        .Join(
            events,
            targetObject => targetObject.TargetObjectId,
            gameEvent => gameEvent.TargetObjectId,
            (targetObject, gameEvent) => targetObject
        );

// Last we select the target name from the collected target objects.
var records =
    targetObjects
        .Select(targetObject => targetObject.TargetName)
        .ToList(); // The query will be executed at this point.
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please clarify what data the ProfileViewModel should have exactly and from which set should it be selected as I am not very familiar with this syntax.